# Form fields based on custom fields

Tags: custom-field, forms

I need to create a contest forms where the fields are based on values in several custom fields. The form layout is to be somewhat static, except from the contest questions (labels) and the type of those fields. Here's the basic layout.

```
[Label - <Subject>] -based on custom field
[Input - hidden]

[Label - <Question 1>] -based on custom field values
[Input - textfield OR x3 radiobuttons] -based on custom field values

[Label - <Question 2>] -based on custom field values
[Input - textfield OR x3 radiobuttons] -based on custom field values

[Label - <Question 3>] -based on custom field values
[Input - textfield OR x3 radiobuttons] -based on custom field values

[Label - Name]
[Input - textfield]

[Label - Email]
[Input - textfield]
```

Tried [something like this](https://snipt.net/Eyesx/contest-form/) with [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) forms. But can't get it to work. The output is correct, but the form wont submit.

Suggestions on how to solve this? I've looked at a couple of different form plugins (GF, CF7), but have not found anything that can do this.

Comment: Jetpack has a bug and can't properly handle `do_shortcode` http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/1762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution to this was to use [Formidable Pro](http://formidablepro.com/) and the following setup.

```
//**************************************************
// Generate the contest form 
//**************************************************

// Determin if radio or not
add_filter('frm_field_type', 'change_my_field_type', 10, 2);
function change_my_field_type($type, $field){
global $post;
  if($field->id == 8){ 
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q1_type', true) !== 'field') {
      $type = 'radio'; //change field to radio on multi-answer questions
    } else {
      $type = 'text';
    }
  }
  if($field->id == 9){ 
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q2_type', true) !== 'field') {
      $type = 'radio'; //change field to radio on multi-answer questions
    } else {
      $type = 'text';
    }
  }
  if($field->id == 10){ 
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q3_type', true) !== 'field') {
      $type = 'radio'; //change field to radio on multi-answer questions
    } else {
      $type = 'text';
    }
  }
return $type;
}

// Get the questions and multi-answers
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 20, 2);
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){
global $post;
    if($field->id == 8){
        $values['name'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q1', true);  // fetch question from given custom field

        // Get data from custom field
        $q1_radio = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q1_radio');

        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q1_type', true) !== 'field') {
            $values['options'] = array($q1_radio); // fetch question from given custom field
        }
    }
    if($field->id == 9){
        $values['name'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q2', true); // fetch question from given custom field

        // Get data from custom field
        $q2_radio = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q2_radio');

        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q2_type', true) !== 'field') {
            $values['options'] = array($q2_radio); // fetch question from given custom field
        }
    }
    if($field->id == 10){
        $values['name'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q3', true); // fetch question from given custom field

        // Get data from custom field
        $q3_radio_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q3_radio_1');
        $q3_radio_2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q3_radio_2');
        $q3_radio_3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q3_radio_3');

        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmeta_contest_q3_type', true) !== 'field') {
            $values['options'] = array($q3_radio_1,$q3_radio_2,$q3_radio_3); // fetch question from given custom field
        }
    }
return $values;
}
```